# Prevent user from turning OFF WiFi using code - Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I'm designing an app which uses wifi for certain purposes. I want to prevent the user from turning the wifi radio off from the wifi settings of the device while my application is running and the device connected to my wifi network. Is there a chance this can be done? I read in WifiManager.WifiLock and they say this: "Note that WifiLocks cannot override the user-level "Wi-Fi Enabled" setting, nor Airplane Mode. They simply keep the radio from turning off when Wi-Fi is already on but the device is idle." Can it be done somehow??

Comment: So say you figure out how to override airplane mode. What if your user is running your app while in an airplane?

Comment: Please don't! At first, you shouldn't do such a thing. Moreover, the WifiManager tells you you **can't**. So please, don't try to code *against* the user

Comment: just ignore the airplane mode. that's not my concern. I just want to prevent user from turning wifi radio off from the wifi settings of the device. i know this is cruel but i wana do it somehow. can u guys give me any idea?

Comment: OK. Next question. Why do you want to do this? Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent the user from turning off the wifi from your code. Even if you find out an evil way to do it , you should not try to do it. If I find out any app in my phone does evil things like these, I will just remove the app. *I am sure* most people are just like me.

If you really want to do it for some reason , perhaps you could tell us what the scenario is and we might be able to help you with a different solution *you havent thought about*

Comment: It was a simple question and I've figured out no one can do that. But i can turn the wifi on again immediately when the user turns it off.

Comment: Yes you can turn it on again when the user turn it off. How evil is that? Please dont do it.

Comment: Yeah its more or less the same. I can show a dialog when user turns off the wifi saying: this app requires wifi connectivity, do u wanna turn it on? and act upon user input. that makes it faithful to the app as well as for the user.

Comment: Yes i agree to that. If your app can only work with wi-fi turned on, you can request the user to turn it on by showing a dialog with a button. if the user doesnt want to, he can close the app. if not he can turn wifi on, That is not evil at all. Infact an app by my mobile provider wants wifi to be turned off when i use the app , and they use the same method you suggested

Comment: Reason: Corporate-owned, single-use device.https://developer.android.com/work/cosu

Comment: There should be a way to do this, if we have  the root access.